# Signature for KeyDown on a ComboBox

Tags: mvvm, mvvm-light, blend

I have a WPF desktop app in Visual Studio 2015 with Blend Extensions. I want to add a `EventTrigger` in a `ComboBox` for the `KeyDown` event but when I press a key (ESC) I get the following Error: `Could not find method named 'ComboBoxExitingStrategyKeyDown' on object of type 'ComboBox' that matches the expected signature.`

My XMAL Looks like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:se="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
         xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
<ComboBox x:Name="myComboBox" Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="1" 
                    Style="{StaticResource MasterComboBox}"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=InternalSourceItems, Mode=OneWay}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=InternalItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    Text="{Binding Path=InternalItemSelectedValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    SelectedValuePath="InternalValueItemDescription"
                    Margin="6,5,6,7">
              <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=myComboBox}" EventName="KeyDown">
                    <se:CallMethodAction MethodName="ComboBoxExitingStrategyKeyDown" 
                                         TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=myComboBox}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
              </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

The method has this signature:

```
public void ComboBoxExitingStrategyKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Good");
}
```

I have tried everything, protected, private, public, no parameters, only one, `RoutedEventArgs` and always get the message.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

`TargetObject` is the object that contains the method.

Currently you have it pointing to a standard `ComboBox`, which does not contain the method.

Since your method is in the code behind of `MyserControl`, you should point it at that instead (by adding a name like you did with the combo)